# Pass navigation params to second screen component state react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am navigating from screen A to B with a params of object using the react navigation life cycle method `onWillFocus` and I need after navigating to screen and `onWillFocus` fire to set the `payload.state.params` to the component state.

I tried it but state return undefined, how might I use life cycle to fetch sent params and use that saved params to fetch data from API in the same component life cycle. and save it to the state to use it in that new screen.

my render function:

```
render(){
    <navigationEvents
        onWillFocus={payload => this.getSessionData(payload)}
    />
}
```

the function it calls:

```
getSessionData = (session_data) => {
    const session = session_data.state.params;
    this.setState({
        session_data: {...this.state.session_data, session}
    });
    console.log(this.state.session_data);
}
```

Comment: To clarify: you are loading in a whole new page here, not simply rendering component B in place of A?

Comment: yes, what I meant here is navigating from screen A to screen B

Comment: @Andrew What I mean here is setState through react navigation life cycle onWillFocus

Comment: You’re trying to pass a value from one screen to another using the navigation lifecycle events. You need to make sure you passing the value correctly

Comment: You can't just pass the value through props?!